# The matlab plot function doesn't plot my time serie

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series

I created a Financial Time Series using the fints function in Matlab.

So my time serie is:

test3 =

```
desc:  (none)
freq:  Unknown (0)

'dates:  (10)'    'times:  (10)'    'series1:  (10)'
'04-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [        0.0074]
'05-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [       -0.0109]
'06-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [       -0.0036]
'07-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [       -0.0013]
'08-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [   -3.2500e-04]
'11-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [    6.4900e-04]
'12-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [       -0.0120]
'13-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [        0.0079]
'14-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [        0.0150]
'15-Jan-2010'     '17:30'           [       -0.0231]
```

I wanted to plot the series, but it doesn't plot anything. You will find enclosed a picture of the result.I used:
plot(test3);

[image: My result]

Can you help me ? I didn't find any related problem, I have the feeling that the problem is very dumb, but I really can't figure it out.

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason MATLAB adds two entries for each date when plotting the time series, one at the specified time (e.g. 04-Jan-2010 17:30:00 in your case) and one at midnight the same date (e.g. 04-Jan-2010 00:01:00). The corresponding Y-value at the added entries are NaN.

To plot the financial time series you can either:

1. Add a format specifier in the plot command. With this you can get markers but not lines as the line styles will be disregarded because of the NaN-entries:

   ```
   plot(test3, 'o');
   ```
2. Plot and remove the NaN entries:

   ```
   p = plot(test3, 'o-');
   nanidx = isnan(p.YData);
   p.YData(nanidx) = [];
   p.XData(nanidx) = [];
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !